# What should be the Connection String of my project?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2005, connection-string

I have hosted a new website from www.hostingfarms.com. They have a file manager for uploading the website content and backup / restore DB (.bak) of MS SQL. I uploaded it. But when I log in into my website (www.theyuvaworld.com), database not gets connected. I have used this connection string in my local PC

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("server=.;database=test;integrated security=true");
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
```

Should I make any changes here.

Note : I have created a user in file manager's database i.e Username = Nikhil and Password = ******.

I will give any other details if wanted.

Regards,

Nikhil

Comment: I have two DB's. One for CreateUserWizard1 ie "ASPNETDB", and others for my users destails ie "test"

Comment: Always put your connectio nstrings in your web.config or another config file but don't hard-code them in your app or you'll have to recompile and redeploy your app just to troubleshoot a problem like the one you are having.

Comment: OK Sir, but how to do it and use it in .cs file when required? And what is the solution of my first question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out this,

Connection string syntax is

```
data source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|aspnetdb.mdf;User Instance=true
```